# Debugging a code with a board simulator in Eclipse (no hardware)

Tags: c, debugging, eclipse-cdt, stm32, simulator

I'm using Eclipse IDE for debugging a code with an STM32 microcontroller, and looking for a way to simulate the MCU board and not need to connect and use the actual micrcontroller, it is very helpful to run simple codes and testing.

I was using IAREW before and it is possible, it has an option for a simulator driver in the debugging tool and you can run and see the results normally as if the board is connected; i was wondering if it is also possible with Eclipse?

In the Eclipse Debugger -> Debug probe, there are only 3 options which are ST-Link(GDB), J-Link and ST-LINK(Open-OCD); i'm new to Eclipse and couldn't figure out if it could be possible somehow by modifying something with one of those options.

- Update:

I have found a kind of a solution, to add an extension to include the IAR EW debugger inside eclipse:
http://eclipse-update.iar.com/plugin-manager-install.html

It is not a good solution as both IDEs need to be installed, and the project need to be created specifically for IAR to use its simulator, so it is not possible to create an STM32 project and use the IAR simulator for debugging.

Are there other solutions within eclipse, without using another IDE or an extesion?

Comment: How does the simulator driver of IAR work? Is it an extra application that can be controlled by the driver? Is the driver documented? Can the driver be controlled in some way? Don't expect a general purpose Eclipse to talk to any other software right out of the box. You might like to look for a plugin for Eclipse. Did you ask IAR if they know about such a plugin? Why don't you simple use IAREW?

Comment: IAR EW uses a special simulator called c-spy debugger, it let's you choose your exact MCU board and it simulates its completely. this simulator driver is part of the IDE so it does not need any extra application to be installed. I will look for a way to integrate this c-spy simulator with eclipse.

Comment: I've heard of a STM32 Bluepill QEMU but never used it. Anyway, a STM32 real board is cheap, easy to get and fast to program (a Nucleo costs few dollars) so are you sure you really need a simulator ?

Comment: You will not go very far with your debug on a simulator: you will very quickly need real hardware interfaces, real peripherals, etc...

Comment: I have a couple of STM32 boards, but sometimes i need to check some piece of codes quickly and it would be very helpful to just simulate it before connecting the real hardware, it makes sense for many cases.

Comment: Well my experience of simulators (on cortex M3 based MCUs) is that it is not very useful, unless you don't have real boards. Is it also usuallu very slow. So when you say "I need to check quickly" I don't see how it will be quicker with a simulator, when loading a software on a Nucleo takes a few seconds.